# PathTooLongException error when using Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm trying to generate a list of all known files on a file share with Attributes `Archive` and `Offline`.

But I keep running into `PathTooLongException` errors.

So far I've only found that Robocopy can work past the file length errors except that I can't get the same sort of "*these attributes only*" sort of results.

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes A+O -Recurse |Export-Csv E:\temp\StubSearchCorp.csv
```

Gives:

> ```
> Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be 
> less than 248 characters.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Get-ChildItem -Attributes A+O -Recurse |Export-Csv E:\temp\StubSearchA.Corp.cs ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (F:\Corporate\...e A Train & Ship:String) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
> ```

Is anyone aware of a way I can export to CSV a list like this?

Comment: have you tried with the native DIR command in `cmd.exe`? `cmd /c dir /A:A /B /S`

Answer (score 2):

Robocopy is a swiss army knife with MANY options. I think all other tools will suffer from the path too long error. Do you really need all the properties that Get-ChildItem produces in the CSV, or are you only interested in a list of fully qualified file names? If the latter, try this:

```
ROBOCOPY source dest /IA:AO /FP /NP /S /L /LOG:myfiles.txt
```

/L produces a list without copying data.
/FP includes the full path instead of just the file name.
/NP suppresses % progress messages in the log
See the "file selection options" from the Robocopy usage:
/IA:[RASHCNETO] :: Include only files with any of the given Attributes set

Answer (score 1):

Found a Powershell-based solution in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8388650/419956), which explains how to ignore these dreaded `PathTooLongException` loggings. Here's my specific use:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-String "my pattern"
```

For OP's scenario, this would amount to:

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes A+O -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Export-Csv "rslt.csv"
```

One major downside: **this silently ignores all paths that are considered "too long"** for Powershell's taste (just as the command promises). However, in my own case, I merely ment to suppress these errors about `node_modules` folders. Others might land here with the same problem, so I decided to share here nonetheless...